# Mutli-projects build with gradle like sbt

Tags: scala, gradle, kotlin, sbt

I'm basically a scala developer and i have project in scala - sbt recently i've started using kotlin and trying to some parts of my code in to kotlin. I need help in understanding gradle build system.
db-service
queue-service
business-logic
processor-code depends on projects on db-service, queue-service and business logic
another project "X" depends on queue-service and some other service.
Usually in sbt this is something very straight forward you can use ProjectRef to include these projects as dependencies. 
How do i achieve the same with gradle? Thanks in advance

//Update 
sample build.sbt

```
lazy val buildSettings = Seq(
  scalaVersion := "2.12",
  fork in Test := true,
  fork in IntegrationTest := true,
  ...
)

lazy val root = Project("processor-code", file("."))
  .settings(buildSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= //Deps
  )
  .dependsOn(db-service, queue-service, utilities)
  .aggregate(db-service, queue-service, utilities)

  lazy val db-service = ...

  lazy val queue-service = Project("queue-service", file(".")).settings()...

  lazy val utilities = ProjectRef(file("../utilities"), "utilities")
```

i have tried including the project in settings.gradle

```
include 'project'
project(":project").projectDir = "../myProject"
```

and added

```
implementation(project(":project"))
```

however, it doesn't seem working show error plugin already on classpath, then i've also tried creating a submodule and it seemed like it was working but when i was trying to run it throws a `initialization exception`

i've understood that we can configure a project in the following scenario

```
Root project: (contains common build.gradle)
| - subproject A
| - subproject B
| - myapp
```

now myapp easily can depend on subprojects

My scenario (no common build.gradle, each project will have its own build.gradle)

```
| Independent project A
| Independent project B
| my app
```

Comment: Please post your SBT config, so it would be possible to help you.

Comment: See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:project_dependencies. If you want help with errors, you'll have to post the project structure, the build scripts, and the exact and complete error messages.

Comment: You can only depend on another project if it's another project of the same multi-project build. If ther are completely independant, then each project should publish its artifacts to a maven repository, and get its dependencies from there.

Comment: @JBNizet Why is it like that? any specific reason?

Comment: It's like that because that's how Gradle is designed. To be complete, you could use hat they call a "composite build", but I see it more as a temporary hack to avoid publishing a new version while some feature is being tested or debugged in a depending project.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet for helping me understand gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's true that you can only depend on other sub-projects, technically, that's still possible with Gradle.

Since `project A` is a Gradle project, you could pack it with `gradle jar` command. Then you could move the produced JAR to wherever you want, but probably to your `my app` project.

Now it's possible to launch an arbitrary command from Gradle using `project.exec {}`

What's more, you can even write your own Kotlin/Groovy function inside Gradle to do that for you.

That's what SBT is doing for you, actually.